# How to get real diff between patch-set, instead of difference of diff between patch-set (related with rebase)

Tags: gerrit

I think gerrit only see the difference of diff.

Is there a way to show true diff between patch-set?

Assume that I have a base file test.txt :

```
This is first line
This is second line
This is third line
This is forth line
```

I upload a patch A :

```
This is first line
This is second line
This is third line
This is forth line // patch A change
```

Then upload a patch B and merge it :

```
This is first line // patch B change
This is second line
This is third line
This is forth line
```

Now we back to patch A and do rebase, the patch-set number truns to 2.
So the code will be

```
This is first line // patch B change
This is second line
This is third line
This is forth line // patch A change
```

but when I try to see diff between patch-set 1 and patch-set 2

there shows no-diff!!

Answer (score 0):

The only diff between `PS1` and `PS2` in your first Change is the commit message which will have the parent and commit date updated, due to the rebase.

This is because there are no code changes between `PS1` and `PS2`, unless you had to resolve conflicts during your rebase.

If you want to see the diff against the current target branch you can select the diff between `PS2` and `Base`.